# How to pass multiple arguments in ng-if

Tags: angularjs

Hi i have to check for 4 conditions based on the condition i have to display the divm,for one div will be same for 3 conditions and another div will be ofr one condition below is my code

```
<div ng-if="RoleId=='1'||RoleId=='2'||RoleId=='3'">
Hi i am from 1st div
</div>

<div  ng-if="RoleId=='4'">
Hi i am from 2nd div
</div>
```

If RoleId is 4 2nd div is displaying perfectly but for 1,2 ,3 it is not displaying any help.

Comment: Why would the 1st one show if RoleId has to be 1/2/3 in order for it to appear and you pass 4 ?

Comment: @OmriAharon based on login RoleId the content must show 1,2,3 will have same content and RoleId 4 will have different content

Comment: you should use `(RoleId=='1'||RoleId=='2'||RoleId=='3')` brackets and is RoleId in `string` format?

Comment: Which version of Angular is used?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi: parentheses are not necessary.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://plnkr.co/edit/cDhsBIC0i15yAPAXYN7Q?p=preview

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Its working fine, Thanks for your answer  ng-if="(RoleId=='1'||RoleId=='2'||RoleId=='3')"

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i did same as yours previusly but it was not working

Comment: @Sudhir: well, it works in the plunkr. Something must be different between it and your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `brackets`.

```
<div ng-if="(RoleId=='1'||RoleId=='2'||RoleId=='3')">
Hi i am from 1st div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to make a variable in your controller.

```
var RoleId = 1;
$scope.showFirstDiv = RoleId=='1'||RoleId=='2'||RoleId=='3';
```

In your html:

```
<div ng-if="showFirstDiv">
  Hi i am from 1st div
</div>
```

Computing complex logical expressions in html are performance blockers.